# how to iterate and display multiple objects from json in angular 2?

Tags: json, angular, ngfor

I am new to code Angular 2. My question is how to show JSON Format A with a proper formatting. As shown, the result includes whole objects (named Atom) I want to display.
If JSON format looks like B, I can show it using ngFor well. However, in the Json format A, I have to create multiple Atom objects explicitly from result then I can show them using NgFor. 
I do not have sufficient knowledge about Angular 2 and JSON, if you have some idea about this, could you give me some guide for this and which way could be desirable solution?

Json Format A

```
{
  "pageS": 25,
  "pageN": 1,
  "pageC": 2,
  "result": [
    {
      "type": "A",
      "id": "2425",
      "tree": "false"
    },
    {
      "type": "A",
      "id": "1185",
      "tree": "false"
    },
    {
      "type": "A",
      "id": "2680",
      "tree": "false"
    },
  ]
}
```

Json Format B

```
[
  {"type":"A", "id": "2425", "tree":"false"},
  {"type":"A", "id": "1185", "tree":"false"},
  {"type":"A", "id": "2680", "tree":"false"}
]
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {AtomService} from './service/atom';
import {User} from './datatype/User';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#atom of atoms">
       {{atom.id}}
      </li>
    </ul> 
  `,
  providers: [AtomService]
})


export class AppComponent {

  atoms: Array<Atom>;

  constructor(private service : AtomService) {
    service.getAtoms().subscribe(res => this.atoms = res);
  }
}
```

atom.service

```
import { Injectable }     from 'angular2/core';
import { Http, Response } from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Atom} from '../datatype/Atom';

@Injectable()
export class AtomService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { 
    this.http = http;
  }

  getAtoms() {
    return this.http.get('./app/api/atoms.json')
    .map( (responseData) => {
      return responseData.json();
    })
    .map((atoms: Array<any>) => {
      let result:Array<Atom> = [];
      if (atoms) {
        atoms.forEach((atom) => {
          result.push(new Atom(atom.type, atom.id, atom.tree));
        });
      }
      return result;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: *ngFor should have thrown an error in the console indicating it is only usable on arrays. Object A is clearly not an array.

Comment: Yes, I understand that point, which approach can be solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what exactly do you want. You can read the results directly from the response, if you don't want to iterate and create new Atom objects.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="#atom of data.result">
   {{atom.id}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

But I think the way you have it now is actually better, as you should process the data, even though you can bind HTML directly to the result.